# EF - A proper way to search several items in database

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I have about 100 items (allRights) in the database and about 10 id-s to be searched (inputRightsIds). Which one is better - first to get all rights and then search the items (Variant 1) or to make 10 checking requests requests to the database
Here is some example code:

```
DbContext db = new DbContext();
int[] inputRightsIds = new int[10]{...};
```

Variant 1

```
var allRights = db.Rights.ToLIst();

foreach( var right in allRights)
{
    for(int i>0; i<inputRightsIds.Lenght; i++)
    {
        if(inputRightsIds[i] == right.Id)
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Variant 2

```
for(int i>0; i<inputRightsIds.Lenght; i++)
{
    if(db.Rights.Any(r => r.Id == inputRightsIds[i]);)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other's have already stated you should do the following.

```
var matchingIds = from r in db.Rights
                  where inputRightIds.Contains(r.Id)
                  select r.Id;

foreach(var id in matchingIds)
{
    // Do something
}
```

But this is different from both of your approaches.  In your first approach you are making one SQL call to the DB that is returning more results than you are interested in.  The second is making multiple SQL calls returning part of the information you want with each call.  The query above will make one SQL call to the DB and return only the data you are interested in.  This is the best approach as it reduces the two bottle necks of making multiple calls to the DB and having too much data returned.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following :

```cs
db.Rights.Where(right => inputRightsIds.Contains(right.Id));
```

Comment: You should explain how this is different from what the OP has already come up with and why it's better.

Answer (score 1):

They should be very similar speeds since both must enumerate the arrays the same number of times. There might be subtle differences in speed between the two depending on the input data but in general I would go with **Variant 2**. I think you should almost always prefer LINQ over manual enumeration when possible. Also consider using the following LINQ statement to simplify the whole search to a single line.

```
var matches = db.Rights.Where(r=> inputRightIds.Contains(r.Id));
...//Do stuff with matches
```

Comment: Technically that's a 3rd option of one SQL call to just pull back the required result.  That's different from Variant 2 which makes multiple SQL calls and Variant 1 that makes one big SQL call and then filters.

Answer (score 1):

Not forget get all your items into memory to process list further

```
var itemsFromDatabase = db.Rights.Where(r => inputRightsIds.Contains(r.Id)).ToList();
```

Or you could even enumerate through collection and do some stuff on each item

```
db.Rights.Where(r => inputRightsIds.Contains(r.Id)).ToList().Foreach(item => {
      //your code here
});
```